Unity: Unrecognized thread niceness after calling setpriority. Target niceness is -6 and actual niceness is 6 UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent
I am unable to find any solution to this Unity error anywhere on the internet and it seems that I shamefully must be the first to ask and in such a bad form at that. My code is unlikely to be at fault - it would state so in the error. I do not know, how to replicate it, nor what causes it as I have not done anything with the settings so far, but it is there in the console always staring me down - it does not prevent the game from running or building though. It is therefore likely a result of an failure in my installation of Unity. I am currently on a bit of a tight schedule and would not want to have to reinstall Unity for this, if I don't have to.
Error in question:
Unrecognized thread niceness after calling setpriority. Target niceness is -6 and actual niceness is 6 UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent (int,intptr,bool&)
So far I just tried to search for a question with a similar problem. I do not know, where else to begin on this.

Give us some more info. Are you on Linux?

yes. I am on Linux POP OS - it is up to date. I have Unity downloaded from the official Unity website and installed it a few days ago.

Asking because it seems to be Linux only or, at least, you google "Unrecognized thread niceness after calling setpriority", you'll find a couple of unity discussions that seem to point to Linux. One of them has a potential solution, but it didn't work for everyone. Perhaps you should follow up with Unity's bug reporting instead.

I've got the same error, also using PopOS
